# Force close webdriver despite of any alerts

Tags: selenium-webdriver

Is there a way to force close a webdriver inspite of any alerts present?
I know that I can close any alerts using the Alert api, but the issue is that I don't know what other situations which may cause webdriver to be blocked.

At present it hangs on an alert dialog and `driver.close()` does not close it. I need a sure way to simply close the webdriver inspite of anything present that may cause it to block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use *driver.quit()* instead of *driver.close()* for such scenarios.

Comment: Thanks! You made the day for me :)

Comment: Haha, no problem. Enjoy Selenium and Sunday :)